# Homogenise the colour and visualisation of Sentinel 2 mosaicked tiles

Tags: qgis, sentinel-2

I am new to satellite image processing. I have mosaicked an image of my ROI downloaded from GEE. The image is downloaded in four tiles as it is a huge study area.  When I am trying to visualise the image, I am getting one tile always darker. Please see the image below. I tried several combinations by changing the layer rendering to lighten and homogenise the darker tile with other tiles. I could not find the right solution. What can be the possible ways to lighten this tile like other tiles?
[image]